# problema al clonar repositorio con laravel

Tags: php, laravel, git, github, laravel-8

Tengo un problema al pushear con Git a GitHub cuando trabajo con laravel, se debe a que `.gitignore` ignora por defecto vendor, storage .env y otros archivos, cuando pusheo y un integrante de mi equipo quiere clonar este repositorio no puede porque le dice que la carpeta vendor no exíste

hay alguna solucíón a este problema? intenté eliminar `.gitignore` pero el archivo tarda demasiado en subir al repositorio, se agradece la ayuda, los estoy leyendo.

Comment: Precisamente la idea es no enviar el vendor (*¿ya revisaste lo que pesa?*), eso se soluciona haciendo `composer install`

Comment: La buena práctica es usar `.gitignore` para indicar todo lo que no debe subirse al código fuente. Eso incluye compilados, binarios con librerías y dependencias que cualquiera puede descargar usando Maven, configuraciones de tu IDE, etc. No deberías borrarlo; tampoco es razonable que un archivo plano de menos de 50kb tarde mucho en subir al repositorio. Posiblemente lo que tarda mucho es que ese cambio (quitar ese archivo) está diciéndole a Git que suba una GRAN cantidad de archivos que no estaban subiendo. La solución es: buscar un `.gitignore` que recomienden para proyectos Laravel

Comment: @BetaM no entiendo, cuando clono el repositorio, tengo que utilizar composer install? esto lo soluciona? gracias

Alfabravo si, me hacía ruido tener que borrar el .gitignore, entonces la solución entonces es sacar lo que contiene .gitignore en lugar de eliminarlo? no me quedo muy claro igual les agradesco la ayuda!

Comment: Sube de forma regular a github tu proyecto, respeta el gitignore que ya existe, cuando tu conocido lo clone debe ejecutar ese comando para bajarse el vendor

Comment: me quedó claro como el agua! voy a intentar por mi cuenta a ver si funciona, gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git es el control de versión de tu código. Git puede controlar versiones de cualquier código. Cuando uno sube código, por norma general, debe evitar subir cosas redundantes. Esto incluye versiones compiladas del mismo código, entregables, librerías que uno descargue vía maven o similar, etc. ¿Por qué? Pues porque le subes el tamaño al proyecto innecesariamente y pones a todos a subir y bajar MB y MB de archivos que igual vas a descargar por otra vía. No tienen que estar en el código de tu proyecto.

Por lo que sé, que no es mucho, carpetas como vendor tienen precísamente eso: recursos que se obtienen al operar sobre el código del proyecto y que no deberían estar en el código fuente en tu repo, no les tienes que controlar la versión.

Así pues, [otros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25748132/236345) como tú han preguntado qué poner en `.gitignore` para que suba todo lo necesario pero nada redundante de un proyecto Laravel.

Una opción que dan en esa pregunta es:

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/laravel

### Laravel ###
vendor/
node_modules/
npm-debug.log

# Laravel 4 specific
bootstrap/compiled.php
app/storage/

# Laravel 5 & Lumen specific
public/storage
public/hot
storage/*.key
.env.*.php
.env.php
.env
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json

# Rocketeer PHP task runner and deployment package. https://github.com/rocketeers/rocketeer
.rocketeer/
```

Ahí evitas que cosas como el vendor y la ENORME carpeta de node_modules suban a tu código. Esa segunda tiene TODAS las librerías de node.js que hayas instalado y **definitivamente** no debería estar en TU código fuente. TOdos los que hagan checkout de tu proyecto van a poder instalar ellos también esas librerías, por ejemplo. Ahí entra a usarse lo que te indican en otros comentarios, con `composer install` van a instalar las dependencias sin tener que bajar todas las carpetas que tú puedas haber creado en tu entorno local.

¿Se entiende?